# How to get Track Source in BackgroundMediaPlayer in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Code in WP8.0

```
  if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState == PlayState.Playing)
   {
      if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance != null && BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track.Source.ToString().Contains("Claps.mp3"))
       {
          BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop();
       }
   }
```

When i Convert this code into WP8.1 Universal Apps, Replaced BackgroundAudioPlayer With BackgroundMediaPlayer, and i tried the below code

```
if(BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.CurrentState==MediaPlayerState.Playing)
    {
      if(BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current!=null && )
       {
         BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Pause();
       }
     }
```

For Second if condition compare the present source track with user input. How get present Track Source in BackgroundMediaPlayer. Please Help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly get the source from the media player. You need to make your own mechanism for saving the source somewhere after setting it (like local settings) and then checking it.

Comment: How to save the source

Comment: It is u to you, one example is using local settings, as I wrote in my answer